# Gnuplot color interpolation for set of linear functions

Tags: graph, plot, gnuplot, octave

I want to plot N different linear functions in a graph using gnuplot.
Furthermore, I have to colors, lets say red and black.

I want to plot all functions with different colors, so that the first function is red, the Nth is black, and the color of all functions in between is interpolated.

How can I do this using gnuplot?

Note: N is not fixed, so I would like gnuplot to do the interpolation.

Something like this, which I quickly hacked together in Paint:

[image: This picture shows what I am talking about.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possibility to color the lines according to a predefined palette

```
N=6
set palette defined (0 'red', 1 'black')
f(x, n) = x+n
set samples 100
set style data lines
set key left
plot for [i=0:(N-1)] f(x, i) lw 2 lt palette frac i/(N-1.0) title sprintf('n = %d', i)
```

`linetype palette frac` chooses the color from a defined palette using a fractional value. You could also use `linetype palette cb` to use absolute values.

The result with 4.6.4 is

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Any way to get rid of the palette on the right? It doesn't really make sense, why [-10<10] instead of [0;1] as defined?

Comment: Use `unset colorbox` to remove the palette, the `0` and `1` in the palette definition specify only the gradient, but not the absolute values. The complete range of numbers used in the palette definition gets scaled to the `cbrange`.